# JAXB (Grand)child element data not populating

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm having trouble unmarshaling elements of a (grand)child table. Here's the structure of the incoming data:

```
<searchResultDocuments>
    <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
    <pageSize>1</pageSize>
    <results>
        <contentType>text/html</contentType>
        <fileName>theFile.txt</fileName>
        <mainDoc>
            <dates>
                <date>
                    <match>20170822</match>
                    <startOffset>4324</startOffset>
                </date>
                ...
            </dates>
            <entities>
                <entity>
                    <startOffsets>4324 5634</startOffsets>
                    <entityType>featuretype</entityType>
                <entity>
                ...
            </entities>
        </mainDoc>
    </results>
    ...
</searchResultDocuments>
```

The java classes to capture the data look like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="searchResultDocuments")
public class SearchReturnData{
    @XmlElement
    private int pageNumber;
    @XmlElement
    private int pageSize;
    @XmlElement(name="results")
    private List<ResultData> resultData;
//(no setters, getters only in all classes, although I tried it both ways)
}// end of SearchResultData

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ResultData{
    @XmlElement
    private String contentType;
    @XmlElement
    private String fileName;
    @XmlElement(name="mainDoc")
    private MainDoc mainDoc;
} // end of ResultData

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MainDoc{
    @XmlElement(name="dates")
    private List<DateData>    dates;
    @XmlElement(name="entities")
    private List<EntityData> entities;
}// end of MainDoc

@XmlType(name="date")
public class DateData{
    @XmlElement(name="match")
    private String match;
    @XmlElement(name="startOffset")
    private String startOffset;
}// end of DateData

@XmlType(name="entity")
public class EntityData{
    @XmlElement(name="startOffsets")
    private String startOffsets;
    @XmlElement(name="entityType")
    private String entityType;
}// end of EntityData
```

When I unmarshal the incoming data into this structure, I get the proper number of rows of DataData and EntityData, but none of the elements have data. I've tried having and not having setters but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainDoc` class, you need to use an element wrapper on your lists.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="dates")
@XmlElement(name="date")
public List<DateData> dates;

@XmlElementWrapper(name="entities")
@XmlElement(name="entity")
public List<EntityData> entities;
```

Also, your XML doesn't close the `<entity>` item, it should have one of `<entity>` and one of `</entity>` instead of two of `<entity>`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try that out right away. The actual tag does close properly; I was fat-fingering and intended to mention same. The data is coming from elsewhere; I'm just trying to consume it.